# Cardinality of finite sets in first order set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, cardinals

How would one determine if two finite sets have the same **cardinality** using first order set theory? Would there be a formula for showing that $$ F(x,y) \iff 
 |x|=|y|?$$

Comment: Using this formula you can check if any two sets have the same cardinality let $\varphi(x, y)$ be: $\exists f( f \text{ is a function} \wedge \text{dom}(f) = x \wedge \text{ran}(f) = y \wedge f \text{ is a bijection})$. And you can fill in the "f is a function" and "f is a bijection"  with first-order counterparts aswell.

Comment: And if you want to be too picky you can even open the defintions of $\text{dom}(f) = x$ and $\text{ran}(f) = y$.

Comment: I thought you couldn't quantify over functions in first order languages

Comment: In set theory, everything is a set, even functions! Every function is just a set of ordered pairs which they in turn are sets too.

Comment: Oh right, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that a function is a set of ordered pairs with a certain property (namely, being functional).

We can write the following formulas:

1. $\varphi_0(x)$ states that $x$ is an injective function.
2. $\varphi_1(x,y)$ states that $x$ is a function and its domain is $y$.
3. $\varphi_2(x,y)$ states that $x$ is a function and its range is $y$.

Now write $F(x,y)$ as $\exists f\big(\varphi_0(f)\land\varphi_1(f,x)\land\varphi_2(f,y)\big)$. I leave you to write $\varphi_0,\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ as an exercise in formalization. Note that this whole thing really depends on how you encode functions, which is usually dependent on how you encode ordered pairs.

Note that "finite" has no role here, by the way.